# How many times the two cars meet each other?

Tags: word-problem

A and B are two towns 100 km apart. M starts from A and travel towards B and N starts from B and travel towards A respectively at 20 and 25 km/hr respectively. Upon reaching their destinations, they turn back and continue to repeat the journey.
How many times do they meet in 24 hours if they start at the same time?

> As the car N will travel 600 KM i.e. 6 journeys (3 rounds) in 24 Hours, the answer 6 times feels logical as it will definitely cross the other car M at every journey.

Am i correct, or i am missing something.

Comment: How did you get $6$ rounds? If I read your question correctly, $M$ takes $5$ hours to make the trip from $A\to B$, so I conclude it can only manage four journeys (or two round trips)

Comment: @FShrike most probably he meant $N$ for $M$ and vice-versa

Comment: Apology, i mistyped the thing. Edited it.

Comment: Which means for 600 KM, N has to meet M 6 times. Am i right?

Comment: At hour 20, they have met 5 times, but are both in the same city. They won't meet again. (I had to brute force this ...)

Comment: If N and M both start a leg from the same city at the same time, they do not pass each other on that leg (or they didn't on the previous leg, depending on which leg you consider the start/end to belong to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems lend themselves to graphical analysis.

[image: dist vs time]

In the graph, the X axis is time in hours. The Y axis is the distance from $A$ in kilometers.  The line starting at $(0,0)$ traces $M$'s path.  The line starting at $(0,100)$ traces $N$'s path.  Where the lines cross, the travelers meet.

Answer (score 0):

The first time those two cars met they had traveled a combined 100 kms. From here on they met every 200 combined kms traveled (why?). After 24 hours they had traveled a combine of $1080=100+200\times 4+180$ kms i.e. they have met 5 times.

Comment: This may be true, but the "why?" is not clear. If they meet just before $N,$ the faster vehicle, hits either $A$ or $B$, then they might meet when their combined Km s are less than $200$Km. And whilst this might not happen in the example, it's not immediately obvious that it doesn't.

Comment: This is not a full answer but instead more like a hint